# jqGrid doesn't load for one data set

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

We have a number of jqGrids on an MVC4 web portal we've developed. It works just fine on all of them, except one.  It displays the grid, but no data and no pager.  I've been wracking my brains for days on this and I can't see what's wrong.  It uses the same jQuery and controller structure as the other grids that all work fine.  Here's what I have:

The jQuery/HTML:

```
<table id="OrgUnitTableGrid"></table>
<div id="OrgUnitTableGridPager"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#OrgUnitTableGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("OrgDataGridView2", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Pos ID', 'Position Name', 'Eff Date', 'ANZSCO', 'Function', 'Location', 'Reports To'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'PositionID', width: "70", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'PositionName', width: "150", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'EffectiveDate', width: "50", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'ANZSCO', width: "170", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Function', width: "130", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Location', width: "170", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'ReportsTo', width: "70", sortable: true, align: 'left' },
            ],
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [20, 50, 100],
            width: "900",
            height: '530px',
            pager: '#OrgUnitTableGridPager',
            sortname: "Pos ID",
            sortorder: "asc",
            edit: false,
            viewrecords: true,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: "false",
                id: "0",
            }
        });

        jQuery("#OrgUnitTableGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#OrgUnitTableGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

    });
</script>
```

And here is the corresponding Controller action

```
public ActionResult OrgDataGridView2()
{
    WebPortalEntities db = new WebPortalEntities();

    int page = int.Parse(Request.Params["page"]);
    int rp = int.Parse(Request.Params["rows"]);

    string sortname = Request.Params["sidx"];
    string sortorder = Request.Params["sord"];
    string searchText = Request.Params["searchValue"];

    IEnumerable<OrgDataViewModel> rows = db.OrgDatas.OrderBy(p => p.PositionID).Select(p => new OrgDataViewModel
    {
        PositionID = p.PositionID,
        PositionName = p.PositionName,
        EffectiveDate = p.EffectiveDate,
        ANZSCO = p.ANZSCO,
        Function = p.Function,
        Location = p.Location,
        ReportsTo = p.ReportsTo,
    }).Skip((page - 1) * rp);

    int total = (rows.Count() / rp) + 1;
    rows = rows.Take(rp);

    JsonResult retVal = Json(new { page, total, rows }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return retVal;
}
```

When I inspect the JSon that's created, it's got data and looks just fine.  I've searched StackOverflow and across the web and I haven't found anything that seems to work. It's just confusing because my other grids all work fine following the same paradigm.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.  And it was stupid.

Instead of:

```
datatype: 'json',
```

I had

```
dataType: 'json',
```

in the jQuery in the client.  One letter wrong, and the default data type for jqGrid is XML which was why it was throwing a `parsererror` in the `loadError` event.  It's a trap for young (and slightly older ;) ) players.

Comment: This just saved me so much time, I spent half a day trying to figure out why I couldn't get the data to load into my grid and then I saw this.